# Operações com datas (apagar arquivo com data no nome e anteriores a 6 meses) sem usar ForFiles

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, vbs, ms-dos

Faz muito tempo que não mexo com **VBS**, por isso pensei em fazer somente em linha de comando
Preciso excluir arquivos anteriores a 6 meses da data atual, como os arquivos que estou gerenciando tem nomes em base da data que foram gerados nesse layout:

```
bkp_201605.xml
log_201601.tmp
bkp_201704.xml
log_201702.tmp
bkp_201803.xml
log_201802.tmp
```

Então eu fiz assim:

```
set /a lastyear=%date:~-4% - 1
del *_%lastyear%*.xml
```

O problema é que se estiver em **Janeiro** esse meio vai deletar o arquivo do mês passado junto (**dezembro/ano_anterior**), e eu não posso arriscar perder históricos recentes.

Pra resolver eu teria fazer um código enorme para poder calcular a diferença de seis meses antes.

Eu ia fazer utilizando o comando **`forfiles`** para deletar pela data de modificação real do arquivo, porém ele não **funciona** (não **disponível**) no **Windows XP**.

Se alguém tiver uma ideia de como resolvo isso.

Comment: você está utilizando o windows XP?

Comment: esses dois ultimos digitos são o mês?

Comment: **@CristianMota** sim, estou usando WinXP 32-Bits e sim, os dois dígitos são o mês, que vai servir de critério pra quando deletar. Eu estava quase fazendo por linha de comando, mas o código está ficando grande.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por fim acabei terminando o código, como imaginei ficou grande, mas não tanto quanto eu achei que iria (Este SCRIPT ficou um nível acima da pasta FILES):

> **Os comentários mostram como fiz cada etapa**

```
SET YNOW=%date:~-4%
SET YSIX=%date:~-4%
SET MNOW=%date:~-7,2%
SET /A MSIX=%mnow% - 6

REM ############### VERIFICAR ANO
IF %msix% LEQ 0 (SET /A YSIX=YNOW - 1)

REM ############### VERIFICAR MESES
REM ### igual a 0 equivale mes 12 do ano anterior
IF %msix% EQU 0 (SET MSIX=12)

REM ### NUMEROS NEGATIVOS
IF %msix% LSS 0 (SET /A MSIX=12%msix%)

REM ### MENOR QUE 10
IF %msix% LSS 10 (SET MSIX=0%msix%)

SET XMLS=bkp_%ysix%%msix%.xml
SET LOGS=log_%ysix%%msix%.tmp

echo ############## DELETAR XMLS ANTES DE %ysix%%msix%
dir FILES\*.xml /b>xml.log
FOR /F %%X IN (xml.log) DO (
    IF %%X LSS %xmls% (del FILES\%%X)
)
echo ####### END XMLS
echo ############## DELETAR LOGS ANTES DE %ysix%%msix%
dir FILES\*.tmp /b>tmp.log
FOR /F %%L IN (tmp.log) DO (
    IF %%L LSS %logs% (del FILES\%%L)
)
echo ####### END LOGS
pause
```

**[Batch Script - Old delete](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VKFIeSOgD__k-tGWo4j7TZ59Qbi8R59I/view?usp=sharing)**

---

Como eu não estava no trabalho fiz no meu Windows 8 pessoal, pra ter certeza de que funcionaria instalei uma máquina virtual no meu notebook, e fiz os testes nela e funcionou, pra ser franco eu estava me atrapalhando num único detalhe, mas por incrível que pareça a linha de comando entendeu os nomes dos arquivo contendo números, por exemplo:

```
REM A Verficar       Data 6 meses
IF bkp_201706.xml LSS bkp_201709.xml (
echo ESTE ARQUIVO TEM MAIS DE 6 MESES
) ELSE (
echo ESTE ARQUIVO TEM MENOS DE 6 MESES
)
```

Retornou `ESTE ARQUIVO TEM MAIS DE 6 MESES`

---

```
REM A Verficar       Data 6 meses
IF bkp_201803.xml LSS bkp_201709.xml (
echo ESTE ARQUIVO TEM MAIS DE 6 MESES
) ELSE (
echo ESTE ARQUIVO TEM MENOS DE 6 MESES
)
```

Retornou `ESTE ARQUIVO TEM MENOS DE 6 MESES`

Comment: tem que juntar as 3 partes?

Comment: Não, os dois últimos são exemplos da própria explicação que foi escrita acima, para entender como consegui chegar ao resultado.

Comment: testei seu código aqui, mas não apagou nenhum arquivo, só criou dois arquivos de textos vazios... o meu continua funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo do código no Google Drive e compartilhei o link. A pasta ORIGINALS é apenas para manter os arquivos de exemplo, a pasta FILES é onde o Batch Script vai gerenciar o que deve ou não ser deletado.

Answer (score 3):

> Suponhamos que seus arquivos sejam todos neste formato como informou e
>   que estejam em uma pasta chamada **"ARQUIVOS**", apenas execute o script
>   no mesmo diretório desta pasta.

o Script irá deletar todos os arquivos com mais de 6 meses.

```
@echo off
cd ARQUIVOS
dir /b>%tmp%\fff.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%R in (%tmp%\fff.txt) do (
set v=%%R
set fano=!v:~0,4!
set fmes=!v:~4,2!
set ano=!date:~-4!
set mes=!date:~,5! &set mes=!mes: =!&set mes=!mes:~-2!


if !ano! equ !fano! (set /a data=!mes!-!fmes!) Else (
if !mes! geq 07 (del /q /f ***%%R) Else (
if !mes! equ 06 (if !fmes! leq 11 (del /q /f ***%%R)) Else (
if !mes! equ 05 (if !fmes! leq 10 (del /q /f ***%%R)) Else (
if !mes! equ 04 (if !fmes! leq 09 (del /q /f ***%%R)) Else (
if !mes! equ 03 (if !fmes! leq 08 (del /q /f ***%%R)) Else (
if !mes! equ 02 (if !fmes! leq 07 (del /q /f ***%%R)) Else (
if !mes! equ 01 (if !fmes! leq 06 (del /q /f ***%%R)))))))))
if !data! geq 07 (del /q /f ***%%R)
set /a arq=!ano!-!fano! &if !arq! gtr 1 (del /q /f ***%%R))
```

Comment: Eu achei interessante o código, mas o **for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%R in (%tmp%\fff.txt) do (** passa direto por alguma razão, o sistema chegou a deletar 1/3 dos arquivos, mas os de muito antes continuaram na pasta. Claro que eu fiz uma cópia dos dados pra testar sem modificar o seu código. Estou analisando o que eu posso ter feito de errado.

Comment: mano, testei com vários arquivos no mesmo formato do seus arquivos... deletou arquivos de 2012 ate 2017. se quiser faço um video hoje a noite mostrando. testei no windows 7

Comment: veja também se a data do Pc está correta.

Comment: Está sim, na verdade eu testei em uma máquina virtual e anteriormente testei no Windows 8, mas eu resolvi o problema fazendo em base do nome dos arquivos, fazendo um algoritimo que retorne o número mês subtraindo por 6 e se fosse 0 ou menos esse número subtrai de 12 dando o mês extato do ano anterior.

Comment: o que pode ter acontecido para não ter deletado todos os arquivos, é esses de muito tempo estarem em outro formato, diferente dos que você mencionou na pergunta, se for isso terá de fazer outro script para esse formato antigo.

Answer (score 1):

Opção sem ser extensa, sem usar o comando **`forfiles`** e compatível com o **`Windows XP®`**:

---

- Código comentado mais abaixo:

---

```VBS
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && cd /d d:\files

for /f "tokens=2delims==." %%i in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value ^|findstr /r [0-9]')do set "_data=%%i"
set "_dt=!_data:~0,4!!_data:~4,2!" && if 1!_dt:~-2! leq 106 (set /a "_dt=!_dt!-94") else set /a "_dt=!_dt!-6"

set "_msg=Arquivo tem mais de 6 meses" & for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%a in ('where .:"bkp_*.*"')do set "_f=%%a.%%b" && call :-[
goto :eof

:-[
set "_f_dt=!_f:~-10!" & call set "_f_dt=!_f_dt:~0,6!" & if !_f_dt! leq !_dt_! (
call echo/"!_f!": !_msg! & echo/del /q /f "!_f!") else call echo/"!_f!": !_msg:mais=menos!
timeout /t 1 >nul & echo/ & exit /b
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- Código comentado:

---

Pega-se a data atual em formato de números concatenando ano+mês com e mês:

---

```VBS
for /f "tokens=2delims==." %%i in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value ^|findstr /r [0-9]')do set "_data=%%i"
```

---

Resulta em uma variável (**`!_data!`**) com o valor **`20190630`**

Obtêm-se a data com uma substring/variável (**`!_dt!`**) de 6 dígitos na ordem ano mês:

---

```VBS
set "_dt=!_data:~0,4!!_data:~4,2!"
```

---

Se o mês é menor/igual que 107 onde positivo/negativo, subtrair 94 ou 6 para data/atual - 6 meses:

**Obs.:** compara-se mês arquivo com mês atual - 6 meses, desta forma: **`if 1!_dt:~-2! leq 106`**

---

```VBS
set "_dt=!_data:~0,4!!_data:~4,2!" && if 1!_dt:~-2! leq 106 (set /a _dt=!_dt!-94) else (set /a _dt=!_dt!-6)
```

---

Cria-se uma variável para exibir mensagens conforme a data/idade do arquivo na tela:

---

```VBS
set "_msg=Arquivo tem mais de 6 meses"
```

---

Implementa-se um for loop para obter: data no nome do arquivo/nome completo + chamada para o `:label`:  `call :-[`

---

```VBS
for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%a in ('where .:"bkp_*.*"')do set "_f=%%a.%%b" && call :-[
```

---

Dentro do **`label`**, filtra-se a data do arquivo via substring/variável (**`!_f_dt!`**):

---

```VBS
set "_f_dt=!_f:~-10!" & call set "_f_dt=!_f_dt:~0,6!"
```

---

Usa-se um  **`if`** para verificar se o arquivo tem 6 meses e assume ação para o caso aplicável:

---

```VBS
if !_f_dt! leq !_dt! (
call echo/"!_f!": !_msg! & echo/del /q /f "!_f!") else call echo/"!_f!": !_msg:mais=menos!
timeout /t 1 >nul & echo/ & exit /b
```

---